# Reseting Google game services achievements through oauth playground for an android application?

Tags: android, oauth, achievements, google-play-games

Is it possible to reset achievements for an android application using oauth playground? I have used it in the past to reset achievements for a web application but don't know how to do it for an android application. I have the android application google game services configuration setup and running but would like to give a method to testers for reseting their achievements out of the android application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm actually going to recommend you try something completely different. The Play Games team just released a new set of management tools that provides a web interface for you to interact with the games management REST APIs, including being able to reset your achievements. You can find them [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/management-tools), along with some instructions about how to use them.

Please note that as part of the setup process, you're going to need to go to the Play Developer Console, jump into your game, create a linked web app, and then use that linked web app's Client ID as the Client ID you enter into the management tools.

Comment: I'm testing the management-tools from github. Is it normal that I don't see any sign-in buttons when I load any of the .html files locally in my browser? I've read the instructions and I'm not sure I've got everything setup properly. Could this affect if the button shows up or not? I've tried in Chrome and Safari on Mac. Thanks.

Comment: @frilla Are you serving the page on localhost?

Comment: @frilla Try going into Chrome's developer tools and see if there is a problem (i.e. click "Console" and see if there were any errors being reported).